# Расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: грамотная-речь, др.-русский

Отдых в Тунисе

Чтобы отдых не был испорчен из-за недостатка информации о предстоящем месте прибывания, полезно знать чем отличается один курорт отдругого. Одни любят тишину и покой – другим подавай грохот дискотек и шумные толпы на улицах.
Московские турфирмы, по рекалмным газетам я насчитала таких более 120, предлагают в основном четыре крупных курорта.
ХАММАМЕТ. Тихий городок, в котором отели расположены прямо на побережье, и имеют собственные закрытые пляжи. Вокруг отелей масса зелени, пальм, цветов. Обязательны два басейна – открытый и закрытый детские клубы, где для малышей созданы все условия (от «лягушатника» до специальных программ из мультфильмов). Этот курорт идеален для отдыха семей с детьми любителей спокойно поваляться на белоснежном песочке, дать отдых нервам, изтрепаным городской суетой.
Добраться до центра городка с неприменной стариной крепостью-мединой – очень просто. Прямо у ворот отеля стоит череда канареечно черных такси. Обойдется поездка в 5 динаров туда и обратно. Месная знаменитость – кафе Тутти-фрутти, где подают изумительно– красивые и вкусные фруктовые салаты и произведения искуства из мороженого разных сортов.
СУСС. Характер этого города прямо противоположный и сравнить его можно с нашим Сочи. Обилие отелей и толп туристов на улицах, зазывалы из безчисленных магазинов и лавочек, кафе и рестаранчиков. Большой красивый порт. В медине по традиции располагается рынок – по восточному яркий и изабильный. Множество продавцов быстренько освоили ключевые русские фразы, типа: «Наташа, давай покупай» и «мало-мало цена».
Собственно закрытых пляжей при отелях практически нет. Между гостиницами и морем проложена набережная, по которой плотным потоком идут автомобили и автобусы.
Поскольку при каждом отеле есть открытые кафе и рестораны по-вечерам здесь организуются программы с лотореями, национальными танцами, шоу Шумно и весело. До глубокой ночи, работают дискотеки, где молодежь «отрывается» по полной программе.
Этот курорт – для резвых юношей и девушек, еще неуставших от жизни. Здесь нервы нестолько успокаивают – сколько щекочут

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы отдых не был испорчен из-за недостатка информации о предстоящем месте пребывания, полезно знать **,** чем отличается один курорт от другого. Одни любят тишину и покой – другим подавай грохот дискотек и шумные толпы на улицах. Московские турфирмы **—** по рекламным газетам я насчитала таких более 120 **—** предлагают в основном четыре крупных курорта.

ХАММАМЕТ. Тихий городок, в котором отели расположены прямо на побережье** ** и имеют собственные закрытые пляжи. Вокруг отелей **—** масса зелени, пальм, цветов. Обязательны два бассейна – открытый и закрытый **;** детские клубы, где для малышей созданы все условия (от «лягушатника» до специальных программ из мультфильмов). Этот курорт идеален для отдыха семей с детьми **—/,** любителей спокойно поваляться на белоснежном песочке, дать отдых нервам, истрёпанным городской суетой. Добраться до центра городка с непременной старинной крепостью-мединой – очень просто. Прямо у ворот отеля стоит череда канареечно-черных такси. Обойдется поездка в 5 динаров **—** туда и обратно. Местная знаменитость – кафе Тутти-Фрутти, где подают изумительно–красивые и вкусные фруктовые салаты и произведения искусства из мороженого разных сортов.

СУСС. Характер этого города прямо противоположный **,** и сравнить его можно с нашим Сочи. Обилие отелей и толп туристов на улицах **;** зазывалы из бесчисленных магазинов и лавочек, кафе и ресторанчиков **;** большой красивый порт. В Медине по традиции располагается рынок – по-восточному яркий и изобильный. Множество продавцов быстренько освоили ключевые русские фразы типа: «Наташа, давай покупай» и «мало-мало цена». Собственно **,** закрытых пляжей при отелях практически нет. Между гостиницами и морем проложена набережная, по которой плотным потоком идут автомобили и автобусы. Поскольку при каждом отеле есть открытые кафе и рестораны **,** по вечерам здесь организуются программы с лотереями, национальными танцами, шоу **"**Шумно и весело**"**. До глубокой ночи работают дискотеки, где молодежь «отрывается» по полной программе. Этот курорт – для резвых юношей и девушек, еще неуставших от жизни. Здесь нервы не столько успокаивают – сколько щекочут